# Autohotkey - Cyrillic characters - different behaviour when hardcoded vs copied?

Tags: unicode, encoding, clipboard, autohotkey

I'm making myself simple script to convert copied text from russian cyrillic to spelling of these letters. I hardcoded some random text like "Вот велосипед" for testing during making it.

Currently I'm using stuff like:

```
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, д, d, All
```

And when text is hardcoded to clipboard in code it replaces and outputs everything perfectly. But when I set it to really read from clipboard it doesn't do anything - it outputs it the same.

What's going on? How do I make it work?
Is there some unicode clipboard read mode or something?

Edit: As suggested - example of nonworking code - not much more than I wrote earlier really:

```
^+!F10::
{
clipboard = Вот велосипед
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, д, d, All
Msgbox,%clipboard%
}
return
```

Outputs "Вот велосипед" - "д" at the end is replaced. But if I remove this "clipboard = Вот велосипед" line and copy it myself instead - it'll not work - "д" is not replaced. Weird

Comment: It should work by default. Add the nonworking code to the question.

Comment: Both methods work fine on my computer... You can possibly try adding a ClipWait after your StringReplace, Can't think of any other reason it's not working for you.

Comment: It works if you comment out the "clipboard = Вот велосипед" and copy from here and then fire the script with it? It replaces? Tried adding ClipWait all over the place - no luck - it completely ignores StringReplace. I think that even though it seems like it's encoded correctly it does not recognize characters in StringReplace, but it does show them like it should - weird.

Comment: Also I noticed that if I'll add russian character directly into msgbox after the clipboard output - it shows "Đ»" instead of a "л". It does also show whole "велосипед" exactly like that if I copy it from here though: "%clipboard% л" => "велосипед Đ»"

Comment: @dyer, are you using AHK Unicode or ANSI? If unsure then try reinstalling it and choose `Unicode` in the setup dialog.

Comment: @wOxxOm It's Unicode.

Comment: Maybe a bug? At least it works on AHK 1.1.21.03 Unicode 32bit, Windows 7 x64